# How can I use imported data as a database?

Tags: c#

I currently have a program that imports excel data into a datgrid in table format.

code here:

```
 private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opfd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            textselect.Text = opfd.FileName;
    }

    private void showdata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textselect.Text + "; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0");
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + textchoice.Text + "$]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
            DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dataGridView.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
            MyConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Browse and Show Data are a button while textselection and textchoice are textboxes.

This successfully creates a table which I want to plot on a chart.

My current chart program uses a database which I must manually insert data into, but I want to use the data that this program imports for me.

Code for current chart (which pulls from simple database) here:

```
namespace StockCharts
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database.Stocks' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.stocksTableAdapter.Fill(this.database.Stocks);

            }

            private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    stocksBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    stocksTableAdapter.Update(database.Stocks);
                    Refresh();
                    MessageBox.Show("Your data has been successfully saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

            private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Clear Grid
                chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
                chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
                //
                chart.Series["Daily"].XValueMember = "Day";
                chart.Series["Daily"].YValueMembers = "High,Low,Open,Close";
                chart.Series["Daily"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date;
                chart.Series["Daily"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Red,PriceUpColor=Green";
                //chart.Series["Daily"]["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Triangle";
                chart.Series["Daily"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
                chart.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = true;
                chart.DataSource = database.Stocks;
                chart.DataBind();
            }
```

Is it possible to assign the imported data as a dataset for my chart to use?

And would I be able to load new data from the first set of code I posted?

Ideally I would like to utilize the Load button that I have set and just disregard or repurpose the database I have created.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dataset: database.Stocks, does it have only a single datatable with your data or it contains more things (relationships/ multiple tables, etc.) If it is just a plain datatable then why cant you create the datatable directly from your excel source and bind it to your chart?

Comment: It's a database with a table inside labeled "Stocks".

My excel source is called through the OleDB function linked to the Browse and ShowData buttons.

Ideally I would like to link this excel source using the functions I've created because I plan to have these tables constantly updated through the OleDB functions associated with Browse.

I'm not sure how to link this excel source to a datatable with the functions I am using right now.

Comment: Do you know if I could send that data directly into the Stocks Database Table?

Comment: Your datasource is not the database but the Stock datatable in the database object. If you create a seperate datatable object having same information as the Stock table, you should get identical results

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. How could I link the showdata function to a newly made dataTable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your comment `How could I link showdata function to a newly made datatable?`

This is what I am assuming: `btnLoad_Click` is your existing function which combined with `Form1_Load` helps you in plotting the chart based on the data you inserted in your database. Now this data is coming from the excel file being loaded in `showdata_Click`. After loading the data from excel I assume you are saving it in the database and then plotting it in the chart.

You want to remove the step to save the data into the database and directly bind the data loaded in the excel to your chart data source.

You can do this by changing the data source of the chart, `chart.DataSource = database.Stocks;` instead of this if you bind it to your own `datatable chart.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];` , it should work (as long as the structure of your table and the stocks table is same).

Posting code, the changes are making the dataset public, and loading the data in form load instead of button click event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database.Stocks' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

                // this.stocksTableAdapter.Fill(this.database.Stocks);
                   LoadData();

            }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        try {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                // System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textselect.Text + "; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0");
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + textchoice.Text + "$]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
                // DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dataGridView.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
                MyConnection.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
    }       

            private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // rest of the function stays same, only change the line shown below
                // chart.DataSource = database.Stocks;
        chart.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];

            }
```

Comment: Sorry, I did word that odd, but you are right on point with what I am going for!

I tried simply binding the data source of the chart with the DtSet.Tables but it doesn't seem to recognize it. I'm assuming because the function btnLoad_Click is private?

Comment: Its because the `DTSet` object is local to your function `btnLoad_Click`. Also before binding make sure you are populating it. Dirty way would be to make DTSet a member of class (so visible across the functions).

Comment: I tried declaring 'public DataTable DtSet;'  in the 'public partial class' section... It doesn't seem to recognize the data when I use the btnshowdata function any longer (also I apologize, I believe I reference btnLoad when I should have referenced btnshowdata in in previous comments..

I think it has to do with the fact that it is declare again in the showdata funciton?

Comment: And instead of 'chart.DataSource = database.Stocks;
            chart.DataBind();'

in btnLoad I put DtSet but I was getting an error about line 88, which contains 'MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);' in btnshowdata

Comment: I just read your updated answer, and for whatever I keep getting errors with the line MyCommand.Fill(DtSet); in the LoadData function as well as the btnLoad function.

Comment: Okay I had messed up some of the data format for the tables, but your code is running the charts!! THANK YOU SO MUCH, I have honestly learned so much through this and I am incredibly grateful. I do still get the error I was mentioning, but I will post that as an answer to this question because I am not sure how to post a picture in this comment. THANK YOU AGAIN. You are the reason stack overflow is such an amazing place.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code useful for you.here i have browse button when i am select excel file.which you are import in gridview.

```
  private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          string filePath = string.Empty;

           OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();

           if (file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
          {
               filePath = file.FileName; //get the path of the file  
                ReadExcel(filePath);
           }
     }
```

here i have **ReadExcel** method .which read data from excel and pass in datatable.

```
  DataTable table = new DataTable();

      private void ReadExcel(string filePath)
      {

                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
                  {
                          ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();

                         IWorkbook workbook = excelEngine.Excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
                              IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                        table = worksheet.ExportDataTable(worksheet.UsedRange, ExcelExportDataTableOptions.ColumnNames);
                              YourDatagridviewName.DataSource = table;
                              YourDatagridviewName.Refresh();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                              MessageBox.Show("No File Selected");
                  }

      }
```

and last you just pass your datatable in gridview DataSource .

Thank you.!

Comment: I am getting errors stating "the type or namespace name ExcelEngine could not be found"?

Comment: here you can need add reference. **Syncfusion.XlsIO.Base.dll**

Comment: Okay, thank you!! I was guessing it had to do with either a namespace or reference. I am new to visual studio and C#, all of your feedback is seriously helping me a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

FULL CODE POSTED HERE FOR LEARNING PURPOSES

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace StockCharts
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Data.DataSet DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database.Stocks' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        // this.stocksTableAdapter.Fill(this.database.Stocks);
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
{
    try {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            // System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textselect.Text + "; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0");
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + textchoice.Text + "$]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
            // DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dataGridView.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
            MyConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
}       

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            stocksBindingSource.EndEdit();
            stocksTableAdapter.Update(database.Stocks);
            Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show("Your data has been successfully saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear Grid
        chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        //
        chart.Series["Daily"].XValueMember = "Day";
        chart.Series["Daily"].YValueMembers = "High,Low,Open,Close";
        chart.Series["Daily"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date;
        chart.Series["Daily"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Red,PriceUpColor=Green";
        //chart.Series["Daily"]["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Triangle";
        chart.Series["Daily"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
        chart.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = true;
        //chart.DataSource = database.Stocks;
        chart.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
        chart.DataBind();
    }

    private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void chart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opfd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            textselect.Text = opfd.FileName;
    }

    private void showdata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
           // System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textselect.Text + "; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0");
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + textchoice.Text + "$]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
            DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dataGridView.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
            MyConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    //
    }
}
}
```

This is the final code that Peeyush Singh https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367497/peeyush-singh lead me to!

This code does produce an error upon startup, which is:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb5Ef.png)

But the program does very much run and inputs excel data, into a datatable, and onto a chart.

SPECIAL THANKS AGAIN TO PEEYUSH SINGH https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367497/peeyush-singh !

Comment: If anyone can help me solve the error I would be very grateful, I am stumped on it..